# undefined method `students_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000003b7a860>:0x00000003b6d6d8> Did you mean? student_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am getting this error for  a while 
my student_controller.rb file:

```
class StudentController < ApplicationController

def new
@student=Student.new
end

def create 
    @student=Student.new(params[:student])
    if @student.save
        redirect_to new_student_path
    end
end 
end
```

and my new.html.erb file:

```
 student infos
 <%= form_for Student.new do |f| %>
 firstname:<%= f.text_field :firstname %> <br/>
 lastname:<%= f.text_field :lastname %> <br>
 <%= f.submit %>
 <% end %>
```

the student_controller.rb file is located in controller folder and new.html.erb file is located in /views/student/
my ruby version is 2.3.0p0 and my rails version is 5.0.0
please any help
and my routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :student
end
```

Comment: instead of `<%= form_for Student.new do |f| %>` use `<%= form_for @student do |f| %>`

Comment: tried it didn't work

Comment: ShareYour routes.rb file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to rename your controller in `students_controller.rb`. Note students is plural.

Also rename class name from:

```
class StudentController < ApplicationController
```

to:

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
```

**EDIT**

You can write your create action as follow:

```
def create
  @student = Student.new(student_params)

  if @student.save
    redirect_to new_student_path
  end

end

  private
  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def student_params
    params.require(:student).permit(:firstname, :lastname)
  end
```

Comment: Did you restart webserver?

Comment: yes i restarted it ,there is a new error :failed to autoload

Comment: Edit your create action with  `@student=Student.new(:firstname, :lastname)`

Comment: the page is rechable now,but a new error accord :wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)

Comment: I added a code sample you can use to refactor your create action.. let me know if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= form_for Student.new do |f| %>
```

will submit to `StudentsController#create` action. Form action will be "/students" and corresponding named route will be students_path, But you have defined singular routes for student

So either

Rename `StudentController` to  `StudentsController` and make resources route plural as `resources :students`

or

Run `$ rake routes`, find student create path & Override automatic form action generation by giving url parameter
e.g

```
<%= form_for Student.new, url: student_index_path do |f| %>
```